# How to get all values from a record when using Group By in Cosmos DB No SQL

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a container having data of various devices, of every 1 minute (For each device the data keeps changing). I want the data of every 4 hours for a particular deivceId from a cosmos DB Container.
Single record for a device with deivceId 0001 is :

```
{ 
  "deivceId":"0001",
  "available": true,
  "temperature": 37.9,
  "timeStamp": "2023-05-16T01:22:29.0000000Z"
}
```

Using the following query I am able to get only the timestamp field of every 4 hours :

```
SELECT max(c.timeStamp) as latestRecord  
FROM c  
Where c.deivceId = '0001'
GROUP BY DateTimeBin(c.timeStamp, 'hh', 4)
```

The result for this query is

```
[
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-05-05T11:22:27.6590000Z"
    },
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-04-24T09:30:55.2280000Z"
    },
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-04-24T08:59:54.4610000Z"
    },
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-04-24T05:59:50.1030000Z"
    },
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-04-14T12:05:59.8910000Z"
    },
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-04-14T11:59:59.8860000Z"
    },
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-04-13T07:46:12.3000000Z"
    },
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-04-06T17:42:55.1950000Z"
    },
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-04-06T14:59:50.5230000Z"
    },
    {
        "latestRecord": "2023-04-04T17:21:29.7000000Z"
    }
]
```

Instead of just the latestRecord, I want all the fields to be displayed, like
**"Select * "**

Comment: Because of the group by you can only get aggregates of the data. If you want to retrieve every document as array in the group; That's not possible. What you could do is retrieve all applicable documents and perform the grouping on the client side.